# A topology on the set of bounded Borel measurable functions.

Tags: c-star-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

Fix a compact Hausdorff topological space $K$.
Define $b\mathcal{B}(K)$ as the space of complex valued bounded Borel measurable functions on $K$ and define $C(K)$ as the space of complex valued continuous functions on $K$. I'm looking for a topology $\tau$ on $b\mathcal{B}(K)$ that satisfies the following condition:

- $\tau$ induces bounded pointwise convergence, i.e. a net $(f_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$  converges to $f$ iff $f_\alpha\rightarrow f$ pointwise and there exists $C>0$ and $\alpha_0\in I$ such that $\forall \alpha\ge\alpha_0, |f_\alpha|\le C;$
- $(b\mathcal{B}(K),\tau)$ is a complete topological vector space;
- $C(K)$ is dense in $(b\mathcal{B}(K),\tau)$.

Does there exist anything that do this job?

The problem pops up in trying to establish some kind of uniqueness by continuity (with respect to some "natural" topology $\tau$) of the extension to the whole $b\mathcal{B}(\sigma(A))$ of a homomorphism from $C(\sigma(A))$ to $\mathcal{L}(H)$ (the inverse of the Gelfand-Naimark isomorphism), where $H$ is a Hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(H)$ is the space of bounded linear operators from $H$ to $H$, $A\in \mathcal{L}(H)$ is a normal operator, $\sigma(A)$ is the spectrum of $A$ and the mentioned extension is performed via spectral measures.

Comment: Respect to the topology $\sigma(C(K))^{**}，C(K)^*)$, each *-homomorphism from $C(K)$ to $\mathcal L(H)$ can be extended to $b\mathcal B(K)$, moreover, $C(K)$ is dense in $b\mathcal B(K)$.

Comment: Thx for the answer, can you provide a reference about where I can find such results?

Comment: This can be found in Takesaki's book *Theory of Operator Algebras I*, lemma 2.2., Page 121. It can be found in Conway's text *A Course in Functional Analysis*, Page 262, "The Spectral Theorem" section, too. Note that this topology dose NOT meet your demmand, but may be what you are looking for.